# Read only borrow inside closure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to borrow a hashset inside of a closure of type `Filter` from the inquire crate
Basically, I want to prevent users from selecting the same option more than once
Here's my code

```rs
pub fn getRotors() -> () {
    let mut selectedrotors: HashSet<Rotors> = HashSet::new();
    let options: Vec<Rotors> = Rotors::iter().collect();
    let filter: Filter<Rotors> = &|_, cur_option, _, _| match selectedrotors.contains(cur_option) { // Borrow occurs here
        true => false,
        false => true,
    };

    for i in 0..3 {
        // Get Rotor from user
        let r: Rotors = Select::new("Select a rotor", options.to_vec())
            .with_filter(filter)
            .prompt()
            .unwrap();

        selectedrotors.insert(r); // immutable borrow occurs here e0502
        // Get char from user
    }
    ()
}
```

I would expect that selectedrotors.contains to only require immutable access to itself so i'm at a loss here

Comment: What is the problem? Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: Like i said, i'm trying to immutably borrow the hashset selectedrotors from within the closure "filter" so I can clear my e0502 error

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to do. You are storing rotors in a `HashSet`. So why do you care if they select the same rotor again? It is a Set!! `insert`ing same element with return `false`.

Comment: @BossMan Because i'm using the inquire crate meaning that this code is user facing. I'm presenting them a selection of rotors to choose from. In the filter function, I am able to hide certain rotors from being shown to the user (ones they have already chosen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the two borrows. There is an *immutable* borrow of `selectedrotors` in your closure and a *mutable* borrow in the loop. There is an issue because you try to take a mutable borrow in the loop while the immutable borrow from the closure is still active (because the closure will be used in the next loop iteration).

You can fix the issue by declaring the filter inside the loop so that the immutable borrow can be released before taking the mutable one:

```
pub fn getRotors() -> () {
    let mut selectedrotors: HashSet<Rotors> = HashSet::new();
    let options: Vec<Rotors> = Rotors::iter().collect();

    for i in 0..3 {
        let filter: Filter<Rotors> = &|_, cur_option, _, _| match selectedrotors.contains(cur_option) {
            true => false,
            false => true,
        };
        // Get Rotor from user
        let r: Rotors = Select::new("Select a rotor", options.to_vec())
            .with_filter(filter)
            .prompt()
            .unwrap();

        // filter is no longer used here, so its borrow can be released
        // allowing the mutable borrow in the next line to proceed.
        selectedrotors.insert(r);
        // Get char from user
    }
    ()
}
```

Comment: If I were to declare the filter inside the loop wouldn't the memory be freed after each iteration of the loop? I want this variable to persist between loop iterations

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about the crate you are using but since you accepted Jmb's answer I would like to point out that your filter is bizarre. Here's a better way:

```
    for i in 0..3 {
        // Get Rotor from user
        let r = Select::new("Select a rotor", options.to_vec())
            .with_filter(|_, cur_option, _, _| !selected_rotors.contains(cur_option))
            .prompt()
            .unwrap();

        selected_rotors.insert(r);
    }
```